# Plain for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I know that python has a for-in loop - which is kind of like a for-each iterator over strings and lists.

But does python support plain old for loop [POFL] like C or java has:

```
for(initialize;conditional;increment):
 body of for loop
```

Comment: No, not directly, but why would you need that ?

Comment: just like that, I saw a few implementations like this:

Comment: for (i in range(list or string))

Comment: You could use a list comprehension with for loop here

Comment: also see `enumerate`